# Creating a function to simplify the multiple plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I need to create a plot for different gamma values where there are like 15  of them, Instead of writing each of them seperatly, can I create a function in terms of gamma so that I can reduce the work ?

```
Z_values_2 = []
for z_star in z_star_values:
    Z = f(z_star, -2)
    Z_values_2.append(Z)

Z_values_4 = []
for z_star in z_star_values:
    Z = f(z_star, -4)
    Z_values_4.append(Z)

plt.plot(z_star_values, Z_values_2, "--", color = "red", label = "$\gamma = -2$")
plt.plot(z_star_values, Z_values_4, "--", color = "green", label = "$\gamma = -4$")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

So instead of doing this 15 times, I need a function that does that for me including the labels with different colors etc ? Is this possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is great that you think of this! This is the way you write good, reusable, modular code: put everything you can in a function. This also improves readability.

OK, you just need to define a function with `def ... :`, what you were probably missing was the [f-strings](http://zetcode.com/python/fstring/) in Python3 (there is guide [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)). It goes like this

```py
var = 42
f"This is text. This {var} is a number."
```

With the leading `f` before the string indicator `""`, you tell Python that there is a variable that needs to be formatted in the string, which is marked between the brackets `{}`.

Here is a suggestion of such a function:

```py
def plotGamma(z_star_values,gamma):
  """
  This function creates a line plot for a certain value of gamma.
  It requires the function "f" to be on the PATH
  """
  Z_values = []
  for z_star in z_star_values:
      Z = f(z_star, gamma)
      Z_values.append(Z)

  plt.plot(z_star_values, Z_values, "--", color="green", label=f"$\gamma = {gamma}$")
  plt.legend()
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()
```

BTW, what is the function `f()` that you are calling?

Comment: the OP seems to asking about each plot on the same canvas. In your code it seems that each plot is done separately